# Adding a column to pandas dataframe using dictionary with indices

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

This must be trivial but I just can't find it.

For a given pandas `dataframe` with some indices, say `idx1`,`idx2`,`idx3` I would like to add a new column efficiently using a dictionary, so something like this:

What is the best way to do it?

```
have = pd.DataFrame({"idx1":{"c1":1,"c2":2}, \
                     "idx2":{"c1":3,"c2":4}, \
                     "idx3":{"c1":5,"c2":6}}).transpose()
newColumn = {"idx1":"col","idx2":"to","idx3":"add"}
columnName = "myName"

#Wished output:
want = pd.DataFrame({"idx1":{"c1":1,"c2":2,"myName":"col"}, \
                  "idx2":{"c1":3,"c2":4,"myName":"to"}, \
                  "idx3":{"c1":5,"c2":6,"myName":"add"}}).transpose()
```

Comment: Please create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Was there anything in the [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html) that might help? There is quite a bit there including how to make a Series or add columns to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
have[columnName] = pd.Series(newColumn)
```

**Output :**

```
>> have
    c1  c2  myName
idx1    1   2   col
idx2    3   4   to
idx3    5   6   add
```